# Recording AJAX requests and Pop ups using Jmeter or Badboy

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, badboy

I am trying to load test a website where lot of images are called via **Ajax** and the very first thing i.e. logging into the application opens up a pop up when we click on log in button. I tried JMeter proxy settings to record it but failed. Also tried with Badboy, and it didn't work out too.

The limitations I have with me is I need to load test it with JMeter only. Are there any plugins available which can be integrated to JMeter so that AJAX and pop ups in an application can be handled in a much better way.

Answer (score 2):

In general, JMeter does not have a problem with Ajax or Popups - so there is no plugin to address such. Both recording and playback happens at the HTTP layer so things like popups are somewhat irrelevant and Ajax is more a matter of timing; but in both cases it is only the HTTP call that matters. So, if you are having a problem, it could be something else that is holding you up. Try playing with the Proxy settings or using a different browser, beyond that you would need to expand 'didn't work out' and 'it failed' into a more detailed problem statement!

One solution - regardless of your exact problem - is to build the testplan manually, this is often actually the easiest way to work with JMeter. You can use a tool like fiddler or charles to examine the traffic and create the requests directly based on what you see. You can also use browser dev tools to do this. You might instinctively think this is going to be difficult but it's not and the added bonus is that the process gives you a solid understanding of how whatever it is you are testing actually works - which is always nice to have.

Comment: But I need to load test a Scenario which says : User Login > Click on any link > Logout.
But the problem is when the user clicks on Login button, a pop up window opens up for entering the login credentials, and that's what Jmeter is unable to record using proxy server settings.
I need to test this scenario with 1000 users but how can I do it because nothing changes in the URL address when the pop up opens up for logging in.

Comment: The popup has no affect on HTTP traffic, it is simply a method to show or capture data using HTML (or javascript etc.). Remember, simply opening a popup is not (probably) going to generate a HTTP request, it will very likely be when you submit the form that a request will be sent. If JMeter does not capture this, the fastest and easiest solution is to simply build the testplan manually.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a tool for testing server-side activity; as long as you record every request to server-side it doesn't care whatever happens on the client. Can you give details abt why JMeter "failed" to record Ajax requests?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have included recording controller to your Jmeter thread group?

I think you are missing with you configuration for "recording controller" or "HTTP Request Sampler"

Some more information about your "didn't work" situation will be much more helpful.

I'll suggest that you should also have a look at the Jmeter Log file(jmeter.log) created in "Bin" folder to understand the root cause of of the issue.

Thanks,